# Can we find by JSON Key and set value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following Object

```
var test = {
  "Employees": [
    {
      "userId": "rirani",
      "jobTitleName": "Developer",
      "firstName": "Romin",
      "lastName": "Irani",
      "preferredFullName": "Romin Irani",
      "employeeCode": "E1",
      "region": "CA",
      "phoneNumber": "408-1234567",
      "emailAddress": "romin.k.irani@gmail.com",
      "active" : true
    },
    {
      "userId": "nirani",
      "jobTitleName": "Developer",
      "firstName": "Neil",
      "lastName": "Irani",
      "preferredFullName": "Neil Irani",
      "employeeCode": "E2",
      "region": "CA",
      "phoneNumber": "408-1111111",
      "emailAddress": "neilrirani@gmail.com",
      "active" : true
    },
    {
      "userId": "thanks",
      "jobTitleName": "Program Directory",
      "firstName": "Tom",
      "lastName": "Hanks",
      "preferredFullName": "Tom Hanks",
      "employeeCode": "E3",
      "region": "CA",
      "phoneNumber": "408-2222222",
      "emailAddress": "tomhanks@gmail.com",
      "active" : true
    }
  ]
}
```

The Object is dynamic (`Employees` may exists or not )

In case the User Id is `nirani` can we set the `active` value to `false` ?

tried as following

```
test.find('userId').disabled = 'false';
```

Comment: You need to turn that JSON into object and then change the value of cerain key.

Comment: If you have `var test = { ... }`  then the `{ ... }` is not JSON but a JavaScript Object. JSON is a string based representation of data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find object by id in an array of JavaScript objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364150/find-object-by-id-in-an-array-of-javascript-objects)

Comment: You have to call `find` on the array stored in `Employees` and you need to use a callback for the `find` method. `test.Employees.find(item => item.userId=='nirani').disabled = 'false';`

Answer (score 0):

You can use native javascript:

```
if (test.Employees) {
  for(var i = 0; i < test.Employees.length; i++) {
    var employee = test.Employees[i];
    if (employee.userId === 'nirani') {
      employee.active = false;
    }
  }
}
```